# Should I use double quotes JSON value

Tags: php, json

I just started to learn using JSON with php and im not sure when to use double quotes and when not to since I got the following error a few times when I changed it around:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'

My code

```
<<< EOT

{

    'id' : 152,
    'price' : '$Z',
    'title' : '$Y',
    'check' : $check

}

EOT;
```

Is this right?

// $Z is the price, but when its getting inserted in the DB it also gets changed to match Swedish ways of writing out a price eg "10000" becomes "10 000" and its no longer a int since it has a space in it and im inserting it using bind_param("s")

so just to make sure should I use: ('price' => '$Z') when im making a JSON value since it can be both "10" or "10 000"

I also have a value $check that can be  "-1" or "0" or "1"

should make that JSON value with double quotes or none? Im not sure since the value can be "-1" eg: ('check' => $check )

Lastly when I got the error message "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'"

I understood is was because ('title' => '$Y')
since $Y = Macbook Pro 15" it wrote out 15" " in the end. Its the best way just to Escape those values right, removing sings like "

Sorry if my questions seems messy, english is not my first languish.

Comment: Don't build your own json. It's pointless when you can just build a normal PHP array and then `json_encode()` it. And so, no, your json is incorrect. keys/values must be quoted with `"`, not `'`.

Comment: @MarcB I think that's what my answer pretty much says. Feel free to upvote it. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing JSON yourself is often going to get you in trouble. Let PHP do it for you!

```
$array = array(
   'id' => 152,
   'price' => $Z,
   'title' => $Y,
   'check' => $check
);
$validJson = json_encode($array);
```

Gives me:

```
{"id":152,"price":null,"title":null,"check":null}
```

Obviously I don't know your `$Z` and `$Y` values here.

And then as you can see by this output, double quotes are needed.

Comment: Cant accept the answer yet but I will. Thanks json_encode solved it!!  Didnt know about that function

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double quotes in json. It doesn't recognize single quotes as valid. [Reference](http://www.json.org/)

Also, if it helps you can use the native php function [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

The inverse of json_encode is [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)